# Notación Postfija en C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++

me presentaron un problema de conversión de notación **infija a postfija**, mediante la utilizacion de la estructura de datos **PILA**.
Si tendrian algun algoritmo o algun pseudo lo bastante claro como para guiarme y que explique la jerarquia de operadores. Gracias

Comment: Hola @VeljkoNikcevich. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Creo que se podría mejorar un poco el formato de la pregunta, más aún viendo que recibiste una buena respuesta, evitando que sea tan amplia. Quizás te sea útil leer [ask]. En vez de pedir que te "*den algún código*", me concentraría en describir el problema específico por el cual no estabas pudiendo solucionarlo, y comentando las opciones que intentaste o que pensaste que podrían solucionarlo (incluso si estaban equivocadas), pero no pedir recomendaciones.

Comment: Esta bien, lamento las molestias.

Comment: No es una molestia. ¡Al contrario! La pregunta de fondo es buena. Por eso creo que vale la pena editarla para que quede una pregunta de calidad (y obviamente se reabriría).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te voy a explicar una idea para que lo implementes:

Lees la cadena que quieres convertir (`s`). Al recorrerla sigues los aspectos que te muestro a continuación, en el orden correspondiente:

1. Si el elemento que tienes es un paréntesis `(`, lo insertas en la cola.
2. Si es un número, lo imprimes directamente.
3. Si es un operador aritmético, mientras el operador que se encuentre en el top de la pila tenga mayor o igual precedencia, lo sacas de la pila y lo imprimes.
   Cuando hayas sacado de la pila todos los que cumplen con eso, insertas el operador actual.
4. Si es un paréntesis `)`, imprimes todos los operadores que encuentres.
   Terminas el proceso cuando encuentres un paréntesis abierto, el cual no imprimes, simplemente lo eliminas.
5. Si al final te quedaron elementos en la pila, los imprimes.

---

**Ejemplo:**

Si tienes `(4+5+9)*2`

- Insertas el `(`,
- imprimes `4`,
- insertas el `+`,
- imprimes el `5`,
- sacas de la pila e imprimes el `+`,
- insertas el `+`,
- imprimes el `9`,
- sacas de la pila e imprimes el `+`,
- insertas el `*`,
- imprimes el `*` y lo sacas de la cola.

Al final te queda:

```
4 5 + 9 + 2 *
```